# Angular Js Search element with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-promise

Hi we have an angular js controller that call a service function:

```
var decodedValue = StaticTableService.DecodificaAllergeni(listObj);
```

this service function get an array of integer. We want to decode this integer in string from `StaticTableService`. There `decodedValue` will be a string array, where each string id the decoded string from int. If int number is `0` not be decoded.

This functiong

```
 DecodificaAllergeni: function(allergeni)
    {
    var elenco = Array();

    var loopPromises = [];                      //Promise for loop
    for(i=0;i<allergeni.length;i++)
    {
        var idAllergene = allergeni[i];
        if(idAllergene!=0)
        {
            console.log("StaticTable IdAllergene: "+idAllergene);
            loopPromises.push(AllergeniService.get(idAllergene));
            console.log(idAllergene);
        }
    }

    //Wait all 
    $q.all(loopPromises).then(function () {
        console.log('forEach loop completed.');
    });
    },
```

I declare promise array and wait `$q.all`(...) for waiting all call are ending.

Every call is made to `AllergeniService.get(idAllergene)` where `AllergeniService` is another service with same element and i match single id with id element. If match return a single element.

```
get: function(idAllergene)
     {
       var deferred = $q.defer();                 
       for (i = 0; i < allergeni.length; i++) {

          //if(idAllergene == allergeni[i].id) 
          //   ...
       }
       console.log("Id allergene che ha chiamato: "+idAllergene);
       deferred.resolve(1);
       return deferred.promise;                  
     }
```

In this case a return always deferred resolve with 1 as parameter.
The problem is that this call is made only one time with first element.

How can call a function n times with different parameter and wait until all call are terminated?

Thanks

Comment: are you making http calls?

Comment: can you clarify your question please

Comment: Seem that when the call is resolved... not for every call